# Why "." is required copying a file from one directory to another directory?

Tags: cp

While reviewing someone's bash script, I ran into following command. My question is why "." is required for copying a file from one location to another? To me it seems unnecessary.

```
cp source/foo.xml destinaton/.
```

Comment: It is not required.

Comment: A better question would be: Why does `cp` require two arguments when copy a file from another directory to current working directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot (`.`) is not required.

You can use the following syntax as well:

```
cp source/foo.xml destination/
```